# Attach Account owner_id to record after create Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im building a `Rails 5` App with `Ruby 2.4.0`

I am creating the Account creation page in which a user creates their account and user in the same form. What I am looking to do is attach the `"owner_id"` owner being a class of `User`. the relationships are all working as when the account is created it assigns the `account_id` to the owner, however it is not assigning the owner_id to the account. When I create the new account and user, I can call them both in the rails console `a = Account.last` (displays the Account details but `owner_id` is set to `nil`) and when I run a.owner in the console it dose display the `account_id` as `1` which is correct.)

I am trying the following call back to set the owner_id to the account after create:

`Account.rb` (model)

```
after_create :attach_owner_to_account, if: :new_record?

  def attach_owner_to_account
    self.owner_id = @account.owner.id
  end
```

I have also tried the following in the `accounts_controller` create action:

```
  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)

    if @account.valid?
      @account.owner_id = @account.owner.id
      @account.owner.role = 1
      @account.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Company subdomain created successfully.'
    else
      render action: 'new', alert: 'There was a problem. Please try again.'
    end
  end
```

my relationships are as follows:

```
Account.rb
  has_one :owner, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :users

User.rb
belongs_to :account
```

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to use this `@account` in the model as in the controller? Is it being defined only in the controller?

Comment: its been removed from the controller (i just used the controller in the question to show what I've perviously tried.) It is being used in the model only as shown in the method at the top of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@account` is an instance method belonging to the instance of the controller class.

`@account` (when used in `User`) is an instance method of the user object.  It's a completely different field and in the user object will have a value of 'nil' unless it's assigned a value somewhere in the user object's methods.

The default key for the relationships will be `account_id` in the user instance. Provided that it exists and has the account's id, then `my_account.owner` will automatically work by building the appropriate query to retrieve the `users` table record with the `account_id = (my_account.id)`

In summary, you don't need an `owner_id`. You can just remove it via a migration. A `has_one` relationship automatically uses the `account_id` in the target class to find the associated record.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in english for me! ive been wrapping my head around this for some time now! Rails magic mind warp...